# Android foreground service gets killes after 24 hours

Tags: android, foreground-service

I am new to Android development and have googled a lot. Unfortunately without success.

My problem is the following:
I want to retrieve data from the device every 5 minutes in the background and then process it further. The whole thing should run 24/7.

Therefore I have created a Foreground Service which also shows a notification. The service starts with START_STICKY.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    setSERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID(R.string.tab_text_locationprofile);

    helperNotification = new HelperNotification(this);
    startForeground(R.string.tab_text_locationprofile, helperNotification.createForegroundNotification(this, R.string.tab_text_locationprofile));

    doWork();
    return START_STICKY;
    //return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

Additionally I have created the permission in the Android Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
```

Maybe it is interesting to know how I stop the service.

```
public void onDestroyDefaults(){
    helperNotification.cancelNotification(SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID);

    //stopForeground(true);
    //stopSelf();
}
```

The whole thing runs fine so far. But after 24 hours the service and the app will be killed.

Many people have this problem, but I haven't found a solution for me anywhere.
Can anyone help me here?
Maybe someone can tell me another solution to do such things.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49782297/7777727

Comment: Thank you, I will try the part with the never ending service.
But I have to wait 24hours :/