# How do some apps run a service on oreo without a notification?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, foreground-service

I want to implement a content or fileobserver that would constantly run in background.
I know that on Oreo I would need to start the service with "startForeground" and provide a notification channel etc., which shows a notification then once it runs.

I wonder how google photos or amazon photos that upload your new pictures do it.
Never saw a notification.
Well actually I just tested it, it isn't instant, at least with Amazon Photos.

Do they maybe use an AlarmManager that is scheduled to run in short intervalls using a BroadcastReceiver (PendingIntent.getBroadcast())?
If you use `setInexactRepeating` that would be also battery friendly.

Comment: They probably use a JobScheduler

Comment: Example of `jobSchedular` https://stackoverflow.com/a/49533086/4762767

Comment: Thanks @Raghunandan - Just looked that up, that could be it. Amazon photos has some options in its settings that are available in the JobInfo.Builder() like "setRequiresCharging"